# oci8, php7 and Oracle 10.1 compatibility

Tags: php, oracle, oracle10g, oci8, instantclient

I have to upgrade a system from `php5.6` to `php7.2`. The system uses an `oracle 10.1` database.

Now I tried to collect all infos but am still confused about the compatibility between `php`, `oci8`, `instant client` and the database.

I read, that with php7 I have to at least install `oci8 2.1`, but this doesn't work with `oracle 10.1`.

Is that correct?

Or is it possible to run `php7` with oracle `10.1`?

Please enlighten me :)

Comment: php 7.2 is the newest release whereas Oracle 10.1 is 15 years old. I don't know if current Oracle Client (12.2) can still connect to Oracle DB 10.1 - possibly it cannot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I read, that with php7 I have to at least install oci8 2.1, but this doesn't work with oracle 10.1.
>
> Is that correct?

No. From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/oci8.requirements.php):

> OCI8 2.0 requires Oracle 12c, 11g or 10g client libraries and will install on PHP 5.2 onwards.

**Note that the Oracle client version you use doesn't need to match the server version.** From the same manual page (reformatted into bullet points for ease of reading):

> - If OCI8 uses 9iR2 client libraries, then PHP can connect to Oracle Database 8i, 9iR2, 10g or 11g.
> - If OCI8 uses 10gR2 client libraries, the database can be 9iR2, 10g, 11g or 12c.
> - If OCI8 uses 11g client libraries, the database can be 9iR2, 10g, 11g or 12c.
> - If OCI8 uses 12c client libraries, the database can be 10gR2, 11g or 12c.

So only the last scenario (12c client libraries) requires a database version greater than 10.1.

Regardless of what the manual says, I would strongly recommend building a test instance and seeing if you have any issues.

---

**Edit:**
Further information from the [OCI8 package PECL page](http://pecl.php.net/package/oci8):

> Oracle's standard cross-version connectivity applies. For example,
>   PHP OCI8 linked with Instant Client 11.2 can connect to Oracle
>   Database 9.2 onward. See Oracle's note "Oracle Client / Server
>   Interoperability Support" (ID 207303.1) for details.

Comment: Ok thanks ... so I can use oci8 2.1 (which is the minimum version for php 7) together with the instanct client which is compatible to oracle 10.1, right?

Comment: That appears to what the documentation says, yes. But I'll repeat: build a test instance and check that it works as you expect.

Comment: @C.Leo If this answer works for you please consider accepting it so that it no longer appears as unanswered.

Comment: thans for the answer, but I'd like to verify this first, then of course I'll mark it as the answer.